# Biometric encryption

Tags: swift, security, encryption, aes, biometrics

I have an app where I allow the user to encrypt some data with a password, store it somewhere, and then have the ability to  read it back again.

To do this, I'm using a combination of `CommonCrypto` for `PBKDF2`, and `CryptoKit` for [AES GCM](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/aes/gcm).

What I currently do whenever the user encrypts some data is

1. Generate a AES GCM 256 bit key from a password using `PBKDF2`, with a random salt.
2. Call [`AES.GCM.seal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/aes/gcm/3243033-seal) like this: `AES.GCM.seal(plainText, using: SymmetricKey(data: key))`
3. Store the result somewhere along with the salt

And this works well. However, I'm trying to add biometric authentication into the app.

Apple provides a tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id), but it seems the api only provides a boolean of whether it succeeded or not. What method could I use to enable the decryption of the data using biometric authentication?

Comment: As you said, LocalAuthentication only lets you know whether or not the user has successfully passed Face ID or Touch ID authentication.  If you want to decrypt a whole bunch of records after authentication, that's all up to you.

Comment: You can use KeyChain and secure it with FaceID/TouchID: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/accessing_keychain_items_with_face_id_or_touch_id